# Publisher provided identifier (PPID) for Google ads IMA

Tags: swift, brightcove

[image]

I am integrating Brightcove SDK for iOS. Along with it I have added a Brightcove-Player-IMA which is a plugin provided for IMA by Brightcove.
While integrating it asks me to provide a Publisher provided identifier (PPID) for IMA ads.
Where does one have to find the PPID?

Comment: Have you find out answer?